# Best practice to remove currency symbol on productpage in Magento2

Tags: magento2.3, price, currency, currency-symbol

I am new to Magento,
I am trying to remove the euro currency symbol from the product page, in Magento 2.3.

In the following file it seems that I can adjust the price, value, and currency:

`vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml`

Is it possible to remove the currency symbol by adjusting this file?

The following code is displayed in this file

```
<?php /** @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\Amount $block */ ?>

<span class="price-container <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getAdjustmentCssClasses() ?>"
        <?= $block->getSchema() ? ' itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer"' : '' ?>>
    <?php if ($block->getDisplayLabel()): ?>
        <span class="price-label"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getDisplayLabel() ?></span>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <span <?php if ($block->getPriceId()): ?> id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getPriceId() ?>"<?php endif;?>
        <?= ($block->getPriceDisplayLabel()) ? 'data-label="' . $block->getPriceDisplayLabel() . $block->getPriceDisplayInclExclTaxes() . '"' : '' ?>
        data-price-amount="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getDisplayValue() ?>"
        data-price-type="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getPriceType() ?>"
        class="price-wrapper <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getPriceWrapperCss() ?>"
    ><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->formatCurrency($block->getDisplayValue(), (bool)$block->getIncludeContainer()) ?></span>
    <?php if ($block->hasAdjustmentsHtml()): ?>
        <?= $block->getAdjustmentsHtml() ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($block->getSchema()): ?>
        <meta itemprop="price" content="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getDisplayValue() ?>" />
        <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getDisplayCurrencyCode() ?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>
</span>
```

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/260054/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the product page I think you can look at `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/web/js/price-box.js`

Around line no 149 you will see `price.formatted = utils.formatPrice(price.final, priceFormat);`

You check it in `console.log(price.formatted);` it will show the string which is displaying at the product page.

So you can change it as your requirement like below.

```
price.formatted = utils.formatPrice(price.final, priceFormat);
price.formatted = price.formatted.replace("$", "");
```

If this does not work then you can [try out this](https://amasty.com/knowledge-base/how-to-remove-currency-sign-for-price-attribute.html) as well. Maybe it helps.

Comment: The Amasty link is for attributes not product price. Altough the preg replace might be usefull.